# Show that $G / H \simeq G^{\prime} .$ Hence show that there does not exist any homomorphism from $Z_{9}$ onto $Z_{6}$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

**Question:** Let $G$ and $G^{\prime}$ be two groups and $\phi: G \rightarrow G^{\prime}$ be an onto homomorphism. Let $H=\ker\phi$. Show that $G / H \simeq G^{\prime}.$  Hence show that there does not exist any homomorphism from $Z_{9}$ onto $Z_{6}$.

Progress: I can Show the first part. But I stuck on last part. Can any one suggest me to solve the last part?

Comment: **Hint:** $|G/H|$ divides $|G|$.

Comment: @ Berci I could not understand, can you elaborate, please?

Comment: We would have $\vert G'\vert = \vert G/H \vert = \frac{\vert G \vert}{  \vert H \vert}$. Thus, one would get $6=9/\vert H \vert$, which is clearly not possible.

Comment: Your first part is [the first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems). For your second question I assume you meant "does not exist any **onto** homomorphism", otherwise this is not true.

Comment: Remember that $G/H$ is the disjoint union of the cosets of $H$ in $G$, each of which has size $|H|$. Therefore, $|G/H|=|G|/|H|$.